# Texture ambiguty when integrating jpct-ae with vuforia

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures, vuforia, jpct

I successfully integrated vuforia and jpct-ae. I can download .obj model with its .Mtl file and texture file, and load it using jpct-ae loader on marker detection. 3D model is displayed very well over image target but without Texture (Material is fine). On digging more I found out that in when I declare texture in my Renderer class it takes as JPCT-ae Texture but when i do it in my Main Activity class it take Texture as Vuforia texture. I tried to Explicitly Include Jpct-ae Texture.h in Main activity but then QCAR won't initialize. without Declaring Texture in main activity I don't know how to change/update new texture (downloaded image) in real time.

Basically I need to update texture dynamically uing newly downloaded image.

Can anybody suggest me any how can i solve this problem? Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved ambiguity problem by disabling the getProductTexture() which sends Texture to Native code.
Now I can apply the texture in main Activity as well as in render activity. 
To update the texture dynamically I used jpct-ae's ReplaceTexture(). following is the code snippet (I am not sure this is the best way to it, but it works fine for me)\
    try {
                modelstrm = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));

```
            texstrm = new FileInputStream(new File(TexturePath));               
            System.out.println("Start loading crab md2 model");     


            try {

                System.out.println("Start loading Texture");        


                TextureManager tm = TextureManager.getInstance();
                if(!tm.containsTexture("new_texture")){
                    new_texture = new Texture(BitmapHelper.rescale(BitmapHelper.loadImage(texstrm), 512, 512));

                    tm.addTexture("new_texture", new_texture);
                }   
                else{               
                    old_texture = new Texture(BitmapHelper.rescale(BitmapHelper.loadImage(texstrm), 512, 512));

                    tm.replaceTexture("new_texture", old_texture);
                }

                System.out.println("End loading Texture");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```